# How to have subplots in OMSnx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, osmnx

I would like to plot the different path to go to 2 different destination on the same figure (window) but with 2 graphs.

In order to get two graphs, I wanted to use `plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)` or (`plt.subplot(121)` and `plt.subplot(122)`) but it doesn't seem to be the right thing to do...

Here is my code:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import WazeRouteCalculator as wrc
from shapely.geometry import Point


Cities = ['Annecy, France','Epagny Metz-Tessy, France']


graph_city = ox.graph_from_place(Cities, network_type='drive', simplify=True, truncate_by_edge=False, clean_periphery =True)
graph_city = ox.project_graph(graph_city)
graph_city = ox.consolidate_intersections(graph_city, rebuild_graph=True, tolerance=15, dead_ends=True)

graph_city = ox.add_edge_speeds(graph_city)
graph_city = ox.add_edge_travel_times(graph_city)



nodes = [549, 2269, 1509, 735, 185, 1100, 869, 2592, 86, 10]
```

If I want to plot the shortest path from node number 549 and node number 10 to every other nodes, I tried to apply this code:

```
paths_no_549 = [ox.shortest_path(graph_city, no[0],node) for node in nodes[1:]]
paths_no_10 = [ox.shortest_path(graph_city, no[-1],node) for node in nodes[:-1]]

colors = ['b','r','y','g','c','r','y','b','b']

plt.subplot(121)
ox.plot_graph_routes(graph_city, paths_no_549, route_colors=colors, route_linewidth=4,node_size=1, bgcolor='#FFFFFF', node_color='#111111', show=False, close=False)
plt.subplot(122)
ox.plot_graph_routes(graph_city, paths_no_10, route_colors=colors, route_linewidth=4,node_size=1, bgcolor='#FFFFFF', node_color='#111111', show=False, close=False)
plt.show()
```

However, it doesn't give the expected result even with the parameters `show=False` and `close=False`

**Is there a way to plot 2 graphs next to each other?**

Also, is there a way to add text to the plotted graph (for instance a text under some nodes to name the place) and a legend?